# PyQt QTreeView - simulate selection of new item without using Squish

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have existing PySide6 code.

My class `PyProto` inherits `QTreeView` and implements `currentChanged()`.

I am doing automated testing and I need to move the focus to any item in the `QTreeView`.

When I put a breakpoint on `PyProto.currentChanged()` and click a new item in the tree view, the breakpoint is hit and the call stack only contains two items: `app.exec()` and `currentChanged()`.

**QUESTIONS**

1. How do I simulate the selection of a new item in the tree view in a way that is transparent to the rest of the app?
   Is it enough to call `PyProto.currentChanged()` from my test code?
2. How do I obtain a list of the current items in the tree view so that I can call `currentChanged()`?

[Link:](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QAbstractItemView.html?highlight=qabstractitemview#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.currentChanged)

> PySide6.QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.currentChanged(current, previous)
> PARAMETERS current – PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex
>
> previous – PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex
>
> This slot is called when a new item becomes the current item. The
> previous current item is specified by the previous index, and the new
> item by the current index.

Comment: You do not call `currentChanged`. It is called by Qt when the current index is changed either programmatically or by user interaction, so if you need to emulate selection changes you have to do it either by calling `setCurrentIndex()` or by interacting with the view's selection model.

Comment: @musicamante my code calls `setCurrentIndex()` inside `currentChanged()`; is that wrong?

Comment: Well, it depends. `setCurrentIndex()` obviously results in calling `currentChanged`, so if you're not careful enough you would risk recursion.

Comment: @musicamante so that why would my current code work? The first thing `PyProto.currentChanged()` does is `self.setcurrentIndex(current)` but the app works.

Comment: `currentChanged` is called when the current index *is* changed. If you call `setCurrentIndex()` with the *current* index, it will not be called again, because it's the same one. But that's not the only way recursion could happen.

Comment: Musicamante gave you the answer. If you solved the problem, why not answer your own question?